# How do I tell RequireJS to look in a subdir for certain modules?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, rjs

I am not sure if this is possible, I've tried with a wildcard `*` in the `paths` config.

I want to load requested modules named `jquery/*` from subdir `libs/jquery/src`, but other files should be loaded in relation to `baseUrl`. This is what I've tried:

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    name: "main",
    out: "main.build.js",
    paths: {
        "jquery/*": "libs/jquery/src"
    }
})
```

Is this possible, one way or another?

**Example:**

```
require([
    "jquery/ajax.js",
    "view/table.js"
], function(tableView){

    var t = new tableView;

    return {
        tableView: tableView
    };

});
```

Would load `jquery/ajax.js` from `./libs/jquery/src/ajax.js` and `view/table.js` from `./view/table.js`.

**Edit**

I have also tried with this `paths` config:

```
paths: {
    "jquery": "libs/jquery/src"
}
```

In both cases I get this error: `Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'Development/rjs/jquery/ajax.js'` while the expected path to look at is `Development/rjs/libs/jquery/src/ajax.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual pattern matching. However, RequireJS can match the start of a path to replace it with something else so you could do:

```
paths: {
    "jquery": "libs/jquery/src"
}
```

With this, then if you do:

```
require(["jquery/foo"], ...);
```

RequireJS will seek `libs/jquery/src/foo.js`. Of course this will be problematic if you happen to want to load the whole of jQuery as `jquery`.

This won't work if you put extensions in your dependencies. You have to remove the `.js` from your module names, otherwise RequireJS treats the name as a literal path and won't go through `paths`.

Comment: That's what I tried initially, but it doesn't work for me, unfortunately. I get this: `Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'Development/rjs/jquery/ajax.js'` Where my baseUrl is `Development/rjs`

Comment: What version of RequireJS are you using? Latest is 2.1.11.

Comment: r.js: 2.1.11, RequireJS: 2.1.11, UglifyJS2: 2.4.12, UglifyJS: 1.3.4

Comment: I think I see what the problem is. I've updated my answer. I missed that the first time around but basically the general rule is "never put an extension in your module names".